# SSAS MDX - specifying calculated measure values

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, mdx, cube

I want to have an output of people with grade greater than 4.75 in the last 3 months. I managed to have this output in the browser:

[image: Browser output]

It would be ok if I had grades greater than 4.75, but I have all values. How do I specify what values I want to have as an output? It's worth mentioning that `sredniaOcenaKelnera` is a calculated value from `Ocena - Usluga Obslugi` measure. Calculation looks like this:
[image: Calculation]

UPDATE

I was trying to write the following color expression:

```
IIF([Measures].[sredniaOcenaKelnera] > 4,75, 32768 /*Green*/, 0 /*Black*/)
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. Values above 4,75 doesn't appear green

Comment: You want to understand how to write a query to get these values or you want to get them from SSMS

Comment: I just want these values to appear in the browser. I tried writing color expression (to at least have these values green colored), but it doesn't work